# drupal, rules, flag, date

Tags: date, drupal, cck, drupal-rules

I am using drupal 6. I have a node called [classroom]. I would like to have a  [vacancy register] associated with each classroom.

vacancy register is a cck type with:
 - uid
 - nid
 - join date

I would like for each user to [register] for a vacancy. I think I can use flag for this.

When a user joins, I can use rules to action an email to be sent to the user and the [classroom]->cck_email field.

1. I would like a rule schedule to also run every 30 days ( configurable ) to alert the user to confirm their [registration].

   1a. If no registration is confirmed, then 14 days later, the user is [unregistered] from the classroom.

   1b. If user confirms registration ( by clicking on a button or url ). then the rule 1 runs again.

I would like to confirms if my approach to this is correct.

#### Update:

I have been playing around with signup, but there are the rules schedule aspect of it that I find hard customising to my liking.

I'm trying to write a rules event for signup_signup and signup_cancel, then action it through rules schedule. But there a bit of existing signup code I have to look through.

Have to do too much custom work to signup, so I thought, its easier to just do it with rules and flags. The downside is having to also create the UI for it.

For the signup module,

I have the following rules event.

Could this be reviewed please?

```
<http://drupal.org/node/298549>

function signup_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'signup_signup' => array(
      'label' => t('User signups to classroom'),
      'module' => 'Signup',
      'arguments' => array(
        'userA' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('UserA, which adds userB.')),
        'userB' => array('type' => 'user', 'label' => t('UserB, which is added to UserA\'s list.')),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I don't know what to do with the arguments list.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the [signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) module for some time, but I think that might be a better module for your case. The flag module is a good choice too, but the signup module is more geared towards what you are doing. Users signing up for content like a classroom.

Comment: I've used the Signup module for a project. It feels bloaty, but it should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: On the other hand, Flag is a more central part of the "modern" lego style of Drupal development, and will let you more easily integrate with all the other new toys. /DA

Comment: Signup will work for most cases out of the box, but it is true that it is more heavy than the flag module. Using it can save hours spent making flag do what you want. On the other hand, if a lot of customization tweaking is needed, flag might be better, as it will be easier to bend to your will. I still believe though, that the signup module will be the better choice in this case.